# Ordering data w/ Middleman and Contentful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleman, contentful

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills here! I've looked all over the internet and cannot find a solution...

**The problem:**

I am using contentful and [middleman-contentful](https://github.com/contentful/contentful_middleman) to essentially create a blog. The content type I am interested in displaying and ordering is called "post". So far I have managed to pull all my posts into /data/blog/posts using the following configuration:

```
activate :contentful do |f|
    f.space = { blog: 'xxxxxxxx' }
    f.access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    f.content_types = { posts: 'xxxxxxxx'}
end
```

*note: I intentionally left out the IDs and tokens*

The problem is when I attempt to output those posts in my .erb file using the following:

```
<% data.blog.posts.each do |id, post| %>
<h1><%= post.title %></h1>
<% end %>
```

This results in a list of post tiles (as expected) but there appears to be no order to the output. I would expect the output to be ordered by creation date by default. How can one go about adding this order or any other order for that matter?

PS, one of the problems seems to be that data.blog.posts is an object with post IDs as keys. That seems problematic. Thanks for your help! I'm just getting started with middleman so forgive my ignorance!

Comment: This question has essentially been answered here. https://github.com/contentful/contentful_middleman/issues/68#issuecomment-170520254.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Contentful does not provide any particular order for your entries.

You can specify order in the `cda_query` configuration parameter. You can find more information on this section of the `contentful_middleman` documentation: https://github.com/contentful/contentful_middleman#configuration

Therefore your configuration block should like like the following:

```ruby
activate :contentful do |f|
  f.space = { blog: 'xxxxxxxx' }
  f.access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  f.content_types = { posts: 'xxxxxxxx'}
  f.cda_query = { order: 'sys.createdAt' }
end
```

For more information on all the ordering possibilities, you can take a look at the Contentful Delivery API documentation: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/search-parameters/order

Hope you find this useful

Comment: Thanks David but I tried this as well and it didn't make a difference. :-/. It seems like no matter what, data.blog.posts is an object rather than an array. So there really is no order.

Comment: Can you create an issue in https://www.github.com/contentful/contentful_middleman so that I can follow up better?

Comment: I actually already have: https://github.com/contentful/contentful_middleman/issues/68. My guess is I'm lacking some very basic understanding of MIddleman.